# How to reimport/copy a shapefile where attribute table can be subsequently edited without changing original shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, copy

I am having trouble when duplicating a shapefile and then going on to edit the attribute table of the duplicate manually. The changes I make are reflected in the original file - hence creating a duplicate doesn't create a separate shapefile. I have tried copying the shapefile manually in the folder but then I found the attributes weren't in the shapefile.

QGIS 2.8.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicating a layer in QGIS only creates another copy of the layer in the map not another shapefile on disk (both source the same shapefile).  When manually copying a shapefile in a directory make sure you grab/select all the sub-files that make up a shapefile (e.g. .shp, .shx, .dbf, .shp, .prj...etc).  If you copy and do not select one of these you may have a newly corrupted shp.  Another option to create another version of a shapefile would be in QGIS to right click on layer and do a Save As and save out another copy of the layer and give it a different name.

Comment: Fantastic, I made sure to select and rename all sub-files correctly, this didn't work for me.

Your second option to save the shapefile under a different name has worked perfectly! Thank you.